# How to deploy a copied WP7 project without removing the original one

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Here is my problem. I made a WP7 application. I copied the project folder of this application in order to make a similar application without having to re-write the same code.

On the copied project, I changed the assembly information etc.., and I also modified the manifest.

The thing is that I can't deploy the copied project on my phone without erasing the original one. Seems like the copied app replaces the original one.
There must be some application identifier to change or something, but I can't find out what/where it is..
Is there a way to fix this, or do I have to start a new project from scratch and copy the files I need?

PS: Don't need to make a class library as it is mainly for testing purposes

Comment: When I change the assembly name, the application won't start

Comment: Okay, I found out the answer. 

The thing is to modify the ProductId in the WMAppManifest.xml file. 
Replace it by a guid (You can generate guid with Guid.NewGuid(); ) 

You also need to modify the GUID in the assembly information. After changing both in the copied project, the application does not replace the original one anymore

Comment: please write this as an answer since your question is on google toplist for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out the answer. The thing is to modify the ProductId in the WMAppManifest.xml file. Replace it by a guid (You can generate guid with Guid.NewGuid(); ) You also need to modify the GUID in the assembly information. After changing both in the copied project, the application does not replace the original one anymore